How do I express a negative premise in Coq?
I would like to express a transition system in the style of the small-step operational semantics as found in volume 2 of "Software foundations". Unfortunately my transition system has rules with negative premises. Is there a way to express this in Coq?
A simplified version of my (failed) attempt:
Inductive tm : Type :=
...
| F : tm -> tm -> tm.

Reserved Notation " t '==>' t' "

Inductive step : tm -> tm -> Prop := 
(* a ==> a', b =/> |- F a b ==> a' *)
| NegativePremiseRule: forall a a', 
  ~(exists b', b ==> b') ->
  F a b ==> a'
...
where " t '==>' t' " := (step t t').

Coq complains that there is a nonstrictly positive occurrence of step in the inductive definition (note that I am still a beginner in Coq, so bear patience).

This is not a Coq issue. Rather, Coq rightfully complains that a relation such as the one you envision might not be well-defined. Indeed, suppose you had another (perfectly valid) premise
| AnnoyingPremise: forall a a' b, F a b ==> a' -> b ==> f(b)

Assuming some b such that b =/>, you would be able to combine NegativePremiseRule and AnnoyingPremise to obtain b ==> f(b), which is contradictory!
More abstractly, viewing inductive definitions as defining a smallest set/relation closed under certain conditions, having negative premises which say that two things are related if some other two are not quickly leads to contradictions and/or to ambiguity, where there is not a single, well-defined smallest relation. This is the essence of the positivity criterion, which forbids such negative premises.
Happily, there is a very standard way to avoid such issues in programming language theory: values. The idea is to inductively define a predicate value : tm -> Prop which characterizes those terms which have "finished computing". For instance, true, 0 or a λ-abstraction are typically considered to be values, while function application usually aren't. You can then replace your problematic premise by value b, and this will solve the problem.
If you do things the right way, you should be able to easily show that being a value implies being irreducible, simply because there are no reduction rules for values. A partial converse, often phrased as "a well-typed term either steps or is a value", is called progress in the setting of programming language theory, and is typically an important property saying that a programming language is "well-behaved".
Most of my explanation is presented in more details in chapter SmallStep of PLF, with a concrete example.

Negative premises are problematic because they can cause paradoxes (see this detailed counterexample). And even if the relation may be well-defined in this case, such definitions can be tricky to work with (what even is induction over an inductive type with negative premises?)
One approach is to avoid negation: replace the negative premise with a positive reformulation. You can prove the equivalence to the negative as a theorem.
(* Positive characterization of terms that won't step *)
Inductive stuck (b : tm) : Prop :=
  (* ... *)

Inductive step : tm -> tm -> Prop :=
| UnstuckF :
  stuck b ->
  F a b ==> a'
...

Theorem stuck_no_step : stuck b <-> ~(exists b', step b b').

